# How to load specific month on elevation event calendar on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, calendar

I'm developing project on rails which use [elevation event calenda](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar)r and I need to load specific month on event calendar how can I do that on rails?